# \umlassoc{Ticket}{passenger} package pgf error : no shape named ticket is known

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

```
\documentclass[12pt,article]{article}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background,foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usepackage{tikz-uml} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{savetrees}
%\usepackage{pgf-umlcd}
%\usepackage{pgfmanual}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlpackage}{airline class diagram}
\umlclass[x=5,y=-6]{passenger }{+ name : string\\  + Age : int   \\  + address  : string }{+ searchflight()  \\  + viewSchedule() \\    + reserveseat() \\  + purchaseTicket()\\  + cancleTicket()\\  + Payment()}
\umlclass[x=5,y=-1]{Payment }{+ Amount  }{}
\umlclass[x=-2,y=-6]{Ticket }{+ ticketno \\  + StartingLocation \\  +  DestinationLocation \\  + PassengerNo  }{ + cancleTicket() \\ + Payment( )         }
\umlclass[x=11,y=-1]{ticketClerk }{+ name  \\   + Location    }{+ reserveseat() \\  + reserveTicket()\\  + cancleTicket()\\ + receivePayment()}
\umlclass[x=11,y=-6]{airline database }{+ id }{ +response()}
\umlclass[x=5,y=-12]{Plane }{+ model \\  +capacity \\  + flightNo. }


\umlassoc{Ticket}{passenger}
\end{umlpackage}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

i run this code then i found an error

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named Ticket is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.28 \umlassoc{Ticket}{passenger}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should pay attention on the spaces.

Comment: As @TeXnician says, `{Ticket }` is not the same as `{Ticket}`, and the same for `passenger`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem was a simple typo.